# Error “Could not read long value, too big with” Memcached

Tags: codeigniter, memcached

I'm using Codeigniter for my website. I have tried setup memcached to cache object from database and when its running i saw the warning like this:

ERROR - 2016-01-12 00:28:40 --> Severity: Warning --> Memcached::get(): could not read long value, too big /var/www/CodeigniterProject/system/libraries/Cache/drivers/Cache_memcached.php 149

How can i fix this?

Comment: I have the same error in Drupal but I don't know cause of this problem :(
Memcached 1.4.15 PHP-FPM 5.5.31
Problem appeared after the updating PHP from 5.3.*

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this happen when values have been saved using the Memcache extension and then are retrieved with the Memcached extension - there's an incompatibility between the serialisation used in the two. Flushing the memcache server should solve the issue.

Comment: This could be the good answer, if you move from ``Memcache`` to ``Memcached`` driver, you must reset the cache.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. To resolve it we have changed the package from php5-memcached to php5-memcache. It solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the Memcached serializer by:

`$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERIALIZER, Memcached::SERIALIZER_PHP);`

(where $m is the Memcached instance).